# Imagettftext like C function

Tags: c, freetype, imagettftext

I need to implement a functionality similar to PHP's imagettftext function. I need to enter a text and output a bmp image based on that. I already looked at freetype but it converts character by character and is not suitable to convert the whole text to an image. I am stuck at the moment. How can I access the source code of imagettftext function or is there another library inc to do that?

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved the question. In GD library there is a function to do (but requires FreeType) that and then you can save the image in PNG format.